# Styling different elements of one class

Tags: html, css

I have few headers, lets say it looks like this:

```
<h1 class='headers'> first one </h1>
 <h2 class='headers'> second one </h2>
 <h3 class='headers'> third one </h3>
 <h4 class='headers'> fourth one </h4>
```

Now I want to style them differently using the class. My attempt looks like this:

```
.headers{
    font-size:4vh;
}
,headers h1{
    color:white;
}
.headers h2{
    color:red;
}
.headers h3{
    color:blue;
}
.headers h4{
    color:green;
}
```

It is not working, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `h1.headers` `h2.headers`,..

Comment: You selectors are wrong...the headings HAVE the class of `headers`, they are not *children* of an element with the class of `headers`

Comment: I think you'll find this article helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors. With regard to your question, the section of the article would be Information: Selectors based on relationships

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, you need to place the HTML tag before the class, your code is designed to target header tags INSIDE of another element, not the element itself.

Also, you marked your `h1` class selector with a comma instead of a period.

```css
.headers{
    font-size:4vh;
}
h1.headers{
    color:white;
}
h2.headers{
    color:red;
}
h3.headers{
    color:blue;
}
h4.headers{
    color:green;
}
```

```html
 <h1 class='headers'> first one </h1>
 <h2 class='headers'> second one </h2>
 <h3 class='headers'> third one </h3>
 <h4 class='headers'> fourth one </h4>
```

Comment: Well, I tried it but i used space, so it didnt work `h1 .headers`
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also do like this, it all depends of course, what you next step will be

```css
body { background: #ccc }

.headers * {
    font-size:4vh;
}
.headers h1 {
    color:white;
}
.headers h2 {
    color:red;
}
.headers h3 {
    color:blue;
}
.headers h4 {
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="headers">
     <h1> first one </h1>
     <h2> second one </h2>
     <h3> third one </h3>
     <h4> fourth one </h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write:

```
h1.headers {
}
```

instead. What you wrote will target h1 elements INSIDE the .headers element.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to select them like this:

```
h4.classname
```